# Magento 1.7.0.2 cannot login to admin locally

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration, cookie

I installed locally magento 1.7.0.2 BUT i cannot login to admin panel!

WHAT TO DO?! I try absolutely everything solution in WEB!

**I tried these suggested solutions**

- Clear the contents of the directory var/cache and try again.
  **still NO ADMIN LOGIN**
- I fixed it by manually setting two core_config_data values in the database.
  They are as follows:

  web/cookie/cookie_path = /

  web/cookie/cookie_domain = "mydomain.com"
   **still NO ADMIN LOGIN**
- I Opened Magento root directory and create tmp folder.
  and Open “lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php“, 
  and locate the following code:

  ```
  protected $_options = array( ‘cache_dir’ => null, replace with protected $_options = array( ‘cache_dir’ => ‘tmp’,
  ```

  **still NO ADMIN LOGIN**
- I also checked my php.ini file there is upload_tmp_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
  **still NO ADMIN LOGIN**

**Whats wrong with local instalations of Magento guys ???**

I still get the same admin page with a a url like this

```
http://magento1/index.php/admin/index/index/key/56d082fb6349c1a302a5afd93ed14e9d/
```

Comment: did you check all browsers..some time magento will not open in chrome

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491819/magento-admin-login-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-fine-for-firefox

Comment: please remove session cache.. in var/session as well as var/cache and also browser cache.. might be it will work

Comment: No, it won't ...

Comment: Did you try 127.0.0.1/index.php/admin ?

Comment: I don't think that works either if I recall correctly. The issue is the way Magento gets the cookiePath. It needs a valid domain name to work properly.

Comment: @webnoob. That's not true. I always use `127.0.0.1` and it works perfectly. It doesn't work with `localhost`. It needs a dot (`.`) in the domain name.

Comment: If you are facing this issue only in chrome, then go to chrome settings and try login after deleting chrome user.

Comment: I've tried everything as above. But It still isn't resolved yet.
I loged in but the webpage is blank at http://<mydomain>/index.php/admin/admin/index/index/key/3fe8e8c2de82e6a28e49a91ac2e2c0ad/ I see cookies at browser, there are 2 cookies with different domain:
adminhtml | 0cu5erkfgnb0usqturgi6lnsu7 | tudiencomposite.com | / | Session | 35
adminhtml | 0cu5erkfgnb0usqturgi6lnsu7 |.tudiencomposite.com | / |Mon, 07 Oct 2013 05:13:31 GMT | 35 |✓ Who can help me?

Answer (score 8):

This so far is the best solution rather than changing the code elsewhere:

Using phpMyAdmin, in your Magento database, look for the `core_config_data`table and open it. Click the "Search" tab. Then on the "path" column set the operator to `LIKE %...%` and the Value to cookie and click the "Go" button to search.

After searching, set the value of `web/cookie/cookie_path`, `web/cookie/cookie_domain`, `web/cookie/cookie_httponly`, and `web/browser_capabilities/cookies` to `NULL`

See also: http://iamtheshadowonthesun.blogspot.com/2012/10/magento-cannot-login-to-admin-panel.html

Comment: i think its better solution

Comment: best solution, I just had this issue after ubuntu upgrade, now it works without touching the code

Comment: perfect answer for this question. This helps me out.

Answer (score 5):

I had an issue where magento wouldn't work without a valid domain name, with that in mind, I changed my hosts file in windows so the localhost entry read like:

```
127.0.0.1 www.localhost.com
```

I then updated all the options in Magento's `core_config_data` table to point to my new domain name and it worked like a charm.

This saves having to comment out code locally.

As per the comments below:

1. The reason this works is not that it's a domain name, it's because the Url then contains a (`.`). Using the IP directly would also work.
2. Once you have updated the `core_config_data` table, it's advisable to `truncate core_cache` as well.

Comment: Hi @webnoob..i think  he already did it in   core_config_data ..

Comment: Yes but if that Url doesn't work locally (because the host file is wrong) then setting it in `core_config_data` won't help.

Comment: I think so..He may be change in Abstract file...remove this line call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);

Comment: ++ webnoob  --  Might I add, whenever we change core_config_data, it's always best to `TRUNCATE` core_cache as well, since we can't access the admin panel to do it the "Magento" way ..

Answer (score 1):

try this

1. Go to
   **`<localhost location>\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract`**
2. Open the file Varien.php
3. Go to line no. 108

remove this line or comment this line

```
call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);
```

and then modified this code (line number 86)

```
$cookieParams = array(
'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
'path' => $cookie->getPath(),
//'domain' => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
//'secure' => $cookie->isSecure(),
//'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

thats all..
further more details [READ THIS](http://opensourcecmsinfo.com/how-to-solve-magento-admin-login-not-working-at-localhost/)

Comment: please say downvote reasons? i just facing this error and i solved it...

Comment: downvoted not by me but obviously because you dont need to hack the core with web findings if the problem can be solved truely / with knowledge.

Comment: Thank you @MischaLeiss..obviously, I had face this kind of problem and solved by using above coding..many time i had solved it..

Comment: read this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491819/magento-admin-login-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-fine-for-firefox

Comment: While this should not be considered a permanent solution, it DID allow me to solve my problem of a mis-configured cookie domain.

Comment: I would highly discourage editing Magento Core files. I would advise to change the configuration itself in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

in db: core_config_data

- cookie_domain 127.0.0.1
- cookie_path should be empty

change anything looking like your domain to

- 127.0.0.1\localcopy\

In app\etc\local.xml (check to have localhost)

In .htaccess disable the following if you had them enabled

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# 301 direct to preferred domain
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^your.domain.something$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.domain.something/$1 [L,R=301]
# End 301 direct
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently with Magento 1.9.2.1.

I downloaded a copy to my local MAMP setup and could not login to the administration.

Always got the message that the formkey was invalid.

I tried everything mentioned in this and other threads:

Clearing folder /var/cache/ & /var/session/
Changing the urls in the database (table core_config_data) and checking if the cookie domain values were set.

No dice.

Then I found the solution:

1. Check your logs in /var/logs for errors.

In my case the session was unable to initialize because it was set to use memcached, which I don't have on my local server.

2. I updated my session handler in /app/etc/local.xml to use files instead of memcached

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is quite old, but yesterday I had the same problem:
couldn't log in to admin and admin login page redirected to url with double index in the url like this:

http://www.mymagentosite.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/56d082fb6349c1a302a5afd93ed14e9d/

..and having spent 4 hours trying to solve it, I share my solution here: I realized that I had access to my admin using my smartphone with 4G connexion. The problem was therefore the IP address that was filtered. The culprit: the MageFirewall extension in which I did not fill in the whitelist.

Answer (score -1):

1) Go to `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract`

2) Open the file `Varien.php`

Comment the below line

```
call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);
```

Comment: I would highly discourage editing Magento Core files. I would advise to change the configuration itself in order to get this to work.