# Magento admin login Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page in Ubuntu

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have work with Magento 1.9.2.4 in Ubuntu OS, my one of the colleagues work with the same project in Window 7 OS,i am newly configured my project in Ubuntu OS

when i login via the backend it show me the error "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page".

But for my colleagues its working well.

My localhost URL :
1) localhost/workspace/magento/index.php/admin
2) mylocalip/workspace/magento/index.php/admin

When i use the second link for admin login there is no issue, but with the first link only throw the error.

For your more information, i was installed the apache2,PHP,Mysql and phpmyadmin.

Thanks advance for your idea.

Comment: Is apache re-write module is enabled.

Comment: i have enabled using sudo a2enmod rewrite, and restart the apache, but still same error showing

Comment: finally i got the solution from this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/magento-1-7-0-2-cannot-login-to-admin-locally